# navigating results in changes of state in react after passing state to Link component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I'm making a purchase invoice app in react.

There are two pages in the app now.
One is a page to create new invoice which can be saved to database and exported to excel file. (Invoice.js)
The other is a page of a list of invoices each of them having modify/delete button. (Invoices.js)

When an invoice in the list's modify button is clicked, it links to the creation-page, and the invoice data, which is a state, are passed as parameter.

Without passing invoice data to the creation page, navigating had no problem at all.
However, after I put 'state' property to the Link component, the following error occurs.

> Invoices.js:21
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')
> at Invoices.js:21:1
> at Array.filter ()
> at Invoices.js:21:1
> at invokePassiveEffectCreate (react-dom.development.js:23487:1)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
> at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:23574:1)
> at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:1)
> at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276:1)

Here are my source codes

// App.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <NavBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact element={<Navigate to="/invoice/create" />} />
          <Route path="/invoice/create" element={<Invoice />} />
          <Route path="/invoice/view" element={<Invoices />} />
        </Routes>
      </Container>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

// Invoices.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getInvoices } from '../../actions/invoices';
import InvoiceRow from './InvoiceRow';

const Invoices = () => {
  const [month, setMonth] = React.useState(new Date().getMonth() + 1);

  const invoices = useSelector((state) => state.invoices);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [invoicesCurrent, setInvoicesCurrent] = React.useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getInvoices());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInvoicesCurrent(invoices.filter((invoice) => Number(invoice.invoiceDate.substring(5, 7)) === month));
  }, [invoices, month, dispatch]);
  
  ...

  // Link component used: invoice is the one of invoice in invoices state
    <Link to='/invoice/create'
          state={{ ...invoice }}>
      <Button>Modify</Button>
    </Link>
```

// Invoice.js

```
const InvoiceComponent = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const invoice = location.state;
  const [company, setCompany] = useState(invoice ? invoice.company : '');
  const [employee, setEmployee] = useState(invoice ? invoice.employee : '');
  const [invoiceDate, setInvoiceDate] = useState(invoice ? invoice.invoiceDate : new Date());
  const [orderId, setOrderId] = useState(invoice ? invoice.orderId : '');
  const [companyTel, setCompanyTel] = useState(invoice ? invoice.companyTel : '');
  const [companyFax, setCompanyFax] = useState(invoice ? invoice.companyFax : '');

  const items = useSelector((state) => state.items);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const last = document.getElementById(`row-${items.length - 1}-0`);
    if (last != null) last.focus();
  }, [items.length]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (invoice) {
      dispatch(updateItems(invoice.items));
    }
  }, [dispatch, invoice]);

  ...
```

I must share current app behavior.

1. When 'Modify' button clicked, creation page is loaded with invoice data.
2. Then navigating with 'Go back', 'Go forward', or clicking a link to any of both pages shows the upper error.
3. in the useEffect hook in Invoices.js that calls setInvoicesCurrent,
   when I console.log(invoices), it is not an array of invoice, rather it is an array of other state(items), which was used in Invoice.js
4. Refreshing the page makes all thing reset.

Is there any guideline for managing redux store when navigating?

> // console.log(invoices) in useEffect calling setInvoicesCurrent  
> // **Normally opened**:  
>  invoices 
>  (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
> {…}]
>  0: {_id: '1', company: 'cmp1', employee: 'e1', invoiceDate:
> '2022-01-07T05:14:15.482Z', orderId: '', …}
>  1: {_id: '2', company:
> 'cmp2', employee: 'e1', invoiceDate: '2022-01-07T05:14:15.482Z',
> orderId: '', …}
>  2: {_id: '3', company: 'comp3', employee: 'e1',
> invoiceDate: '2022-01-07T05:14:15.482Z', orderId: '', …}
>  3: {_id:
> '4', company: 'comp4', employee: 'e1', invoiceDate:
> '2022-01-07T05:14:15.482Z', orderId: '', …}
>  4: {_id: '5', company:
> 'comp5', employee: 'e1', invoiceDate: '2022-01-07T05:14:15.482Z',
> orderId: '', …}
>  5: {_id: '6', company: 'comp6', employee: 'e1',
> invoiceDate: '2022-01-07T13:10:56.380Z', orderId: '', …}
>  length: 6
> [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
>
> Each Array has the following data 
> 0:
> company: "cmp1"
> companyFax: "1222222222"
>  companyTel: "122331232"
>  employee:
> "e1"
>  invoiceDate: "2022-01-07T05:14:15.482Z"
>  items:
> Array(2)
>    0: {name: 'item1', spec: 'spec1', qty: 1, price: 10000,
> total: 10000, …}
>    1: {name: 'item2', spec: 'spec2', qty: 20,
> price: 1000, total: 20000, …}
>    length: 2
>    [[Prototype]]:
> Array(0)
>  modifiedOn: "2022-01-07T05:25:14.771Z"
>  orderId:
> ""
> __v: 0
> _id: "1"
>
> // console.log(invoices) **when ERROR occurs**:  
> invoices 
>  (6)
> [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)] 
>  0:
> Array(2) 
>    0: {name: 'item1', spec: 'spec1', qty: 1, price:
> 10000, total: 10000, …} 
>    1: {name: 'item2', spec: 'spec2', qty:
> 20, price: 1000, total: 20000, …} 
>    length: 2 
> [[Prototype]]: Array(0) 
>  1: Array(2) 
>    0: {name: 'item1',
> spec: 'spec1', qty: 1, price: 10000, total: 10000, …} 
>    1: {name:
> 'item2', spec: 'spec2', qty: 20, price: 1000, total: 20000, …} 
> length: 2 
>    [[Prototype]]: Array(0) 
>  2: (2) [{…}, {…}] 
> 3: (2) [{…}, {…}] 
>  4: (2) [{…}, {…}] 
>  5: (2) [{…}, {…}] 
> length: 6 
>  [[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: What is the value of `invoice` that you are spreading into the route state? Where is `invoice` declared in `Invoices.js`? Seems some code is missing, can you update to provide a complete and reproducible code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not destructure the array to an object, It creates an object.

use like below

```
// Invoices.js
<Link to="/invoice/create" state={{ invoice }}>
  <Button>Modify</Button>
</Link>;

// Invoice.js
const { invoice } = location.state;
```

**Note:**

```
const a = [1,2,3];
console.log({...a}); // {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir.
But the problem still exists.
It works when the Invoice.js is loaded, but when I 'Go Back' or click a link to Invoices.js, 
'invoices' state becomes an array of same 'items' array.

Comment: bacause you are doing `dispatch(updateItems(invoice.items));`,

Comment: why does updating Items state affects invoices state? then should I reset the dispatch function when navigated to Invoices page?